# find general solution to the Differential equation:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

given transformation to solve the following :
$$3x^5-y(y^2-x^3)y'=0 \qquad u=x^3, v=y^2 $$

i get 
$$v'=2yy'$$
$$u'=3x^2x'$$
we have

$$uu'-(\frac{v-u}{2})v'=0$$
how can I solve this equation to get a general solution of $(y^2-2x^3)(y^2+x^3)^2=c$. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$u=x^3\Rightarrow \mathrm du=3x^2\mathrm dx \Rightarrow dx=\frac{\mathrm du}{3x^2}$$ and similarly $$v=y^2\Rightarrow \mathrm dv=2y\mathrm dy\Rightarrow \mathrm dy=\frac{\mathrm dv}{2y}$$

But replacing $\mathrm dx$ and $\mathrm dy$ transforms your ode into something quite nice:
$$
\frac{3x^5}{3x^2}\mathrm du-\frac{1}{2}(y^2-x^3)\mathrm dv=
u\mathrm du-\frac{1}{2}(v-u)\mathrm dv=0
$$

Comment: I think there's a typo in the second line with $\mathrm{d}x$ instead of $\mathrm{d}y$.

Comment: @Jam thanks! Just cause you can copy and past doesn't mean you should :P

Comment: And a typo in the third line with $\mathrm{d}u$ instead of $\mathrm{d}v$

Comment: Sorry to be an ass and point out your mistakes, but it aids clarity. It's a very good solution to the problem :)

Comment: no! I appreciate it! Sometimes I rush too much and dont want to confuse op.

Comment: @qbert thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{du}{dv}=\frac{(1-\frac{u}{v})}{2(\frac{u}{v})}$$
let $$w=\frac{u}{v} ,u'=w+vw'$$
we obtain $$\frac{2w}{(1-2w)(1+w)}dw = \frac{1}{v}dv$$
then 
$$\int \frac{2}{3(1-2w)}-\frac{2}{3(1+w)}dw=\int\frac{1}{v}dv$$
therefore
$$ (y^2-2x^3)(y^2+x^3)^2=c$$

Thank you everybody. I just found it.